# Rice alternative for rice bucket wrist/grip exercise (aka "dirty rice")?

Tags: wrist, grip

Love these exercises, but I live in a very humid climate, and the rice getting moldy pretty soon (plus it is a health hazard). Would you suggest some alternatives?

At the top of my head, I can think of the following replacements:

- plastic pellets (usually used by die-cast shops)
- gravel / river rocks (e.g., from Lowe's)

Have you tried these? Did you find anything better? Thanks!